# Especificar un ruta de archivo .txt en php

Tags: php

hola que pena molestar apenas estoy iniciando con php lo que sucede es que no se como espeficicar la ruta de un archivo txt que se encuentra en otra carpeta de mi proyecto para su lectura, siempre que intento acceder me dice que no lo encuentra.

```
$path="archivos/TRM2021.txt";


$file=fopen($path,"a+") or die("error en la creacion del archivo");
```

el archivo TRM2021.txt no se encuentra en la misma carpeta desde donde estoy intentando traerlo, no se si es que en php el .txt tiene que estar en la misma carpeta que el archivo .php o no se puede importar desde otra carpeta o que? la carpeta archivos donde esta el TRM2021.txt esta dentro del mismo proyecto.

yo estoy en clase3 y necesito treaer el .txt que esta en archivos
[image: proyecto]

Comment: debes colocarlo en la ruta exacta donde tienes el archivo php, si esta dentro de una carpeta ir entrando de carpeta en carpeta separando cada una con un "/", pero si quieres irte a lo seguro puedes especificar la ruta total desde el disco c "c:/users/usuario/documentos/prueba.txt"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Puedes usar ***rutas absolutas*** o bien ***rutas relativas***. A saber:

### Rutas absolutas

**Rutas absolutas**: Son las que indican **toda** la ruta de tu sistema de archivos. Para ello se usa la siguiente sintaxis:

- `/`: Una barra sola al principio de la ruta apunta a la carpeta raíz de tu sistema de archivos. No se usa para rutas relativas, sino más bien para las rutas absolutas. En Windows tambien se puede usar `C:/` o `D:/` o el nombre de unidad que sea donde esten situados los archivos más los dos puntos más la barra. A partir de allí se debe poner **toda** la ruta hasta llegar al archivo que se quiere usar o referenciar.

Por ejemplo:

```
$path="/home/micuenta/public_html/archivos/TRM2021.txt";
```

o bien, en windows seria algo así como:

```
$path="C:/Users/Marion/Documentos/Mi sitio web/archivos/TRM2021.txt";
```

### Rutas relativas

**Rutas relativas**: Son las que parten del lugar donde esté situado el archivo desde el cual estas llamando a otros archivos de tu sistema. Para ello se utiliza la siguiente sintaxis:

- `../`:  Dos puntos seguidos de una barra apuntan a una carpeta/subdirectorio *hacia atras* en tu estructura de árbol de tus archivos. También se puede decir que subes un nivel hacia arriba o retrocedes un nivel en la misma o que te pones en el padre de la carpeta actual.
- `./`: Un punto seguido de una barra apunta al mismo lugar donde estés ahora, es el mismo nivel, carpeta o subdirectorio donde este el archivo que lo está usando. Siendo así no parece que tenga demasiado sentido usarlo, pues si escribimos una ruta sin eso viene a ser lo mismo, pero lo verás frecuentemente en muchos lugares y no está de más saberlo y entenderlo, y hasta usarlo para indicar que sabes donde estás y desde donde quieres llamar a otros archivos.

Por ejemplo, en tu caso concreto y con la estructura de carpetas/subdirectorios que has dicho, la ruta relativa a tu archivo **TRM2021.txt** situado en la carpeta `archivos/` llamado desde un archivo situado en la carpeta `clase3/` seria esta:

```
$path="../archivos/TRM2021.txt";
```

que indica que desde **clase3/** debes retroceder un nivel, para luego ponerte dentro de la carpeta/subdirectorio **archivos** y desde allí ya puedes llamar al archivo **TRM2021.txt**

También sirve para referenciar urls en el mismo dominio, por ejemplo en el atributo `src=` de una imagen `<img src=` o en cualquier enlace `<a href=` o en otros elementos que usen rutas, o en CSS. La única diferencia en este caso es que **en las absolutas debes cambiar el `/` o la `c:/` por el protocolo (normalmente `http://` o `https://`) más el nombre de dominio**, o sea, `https://midominio.com/archivos/TRM2021.txt`. Pero **las relativas funcionan exactamente igual**.

**Nota:** Mi consejo es **siempre usar rutas relativas**, así tu proyecto siempre puedes moverlo de lugar sin tener que variar todas las referencias absolutas que tengas a otros archivos, pues con las rutas relativas se parte siempre del propio archivo, y si copias o mueves todo no se pierden dichas rutas y siguen siendo válidas.

Comment: funciono perfecto las dos formas , siendo si, mucho mas comodo usar las relativas , Mil gracias

Comment: Me alegro que te haya funcionado. También sirve para referenciar urls en el mismo dominio, por ejemplo en el atributo `src=` de una imagen `<img src=` o en cualquier enlace `<a href=` o en otros elementos que usen rutas, o en CSS. La única diferencia en este caso es que **en las absolutas debes cambiar el `/` o la `c:/` por el protocolo (normalmente `http://` o `https://`) más el nombre de dominio**, o sea, `https://midominio.com/archivos/TRM2021.txt`.  Pero las relativas funcionan exactamente igual.