# Error al abrir archivo index.php linux

Tags: php, mysql, sql

tengo un problema, me sale esto

[image: Error image]

La estructura de mis archivos es

[image: docs]

donde en config cargo la base de datos

```
<?php
  class Database{
  public static function connect(){
     $db = new mysqli('localhost','root','1234','alumnos');
     $db->query("SET NAMES utf8'");
     return $db;
  }
 }
 ?>
```

En modelo solo cargo la clase de bd, y cargo un metodo el cual hace un query donde trae toda la tabla

```
<?php

require_once "../config/db.php";

class Alumno{

private $id;
private $nombre;
private $grupo;
private $grado;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->db = Database::connect();
}

//metodos get y set

 public function getAll() //mostrar todo
   {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM alumno;";
    $post = $this->db->query($sql);

    $result = array();
    if ($post && mysqli_num_rows($post) >= 1) {
        $result = $post;
        }
    return $result;
    }
   }
```

Y mi archivo index.php esta de esta forma

```
<?php

  header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://localhost:4200");
  header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-API-KEY, Origin, Content-Type, Accept, 
  Access-Control-Request-Method");
  header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');

  require_once "../models/alumno.php";

  $alumno = new Alumno();

  if(isset($_GET['id'])){ //get with id
     echo json_encode("with Id");
     }else{
        echo json_encode($alumno->getAll());
     }

 ?>
```

Es para mi primer API en php para consumirla en Angular, pero no carga, se que el mal no esta en la instalacion del apache pues si cambio de index a uno que solo haga un echo si carga, este no tengo idea
Gracias de antemano..!

Comment: Revisa los logs de apache, tal vez por ahí encuentres el problema.

Comment: En tu archivo `index.php` como primer instrucción agrega esto `error_reporting(E_ALL);`. Mas [info acá](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.error-reporting.php)

Comment: el tema de enviar Headers con un espacio en blanco entre <?php y Header solia dar muchos problemas. Como te dicen, pon lo de error_reporting(E_ALL); Yo probaria a ir poniendo unos cuantos ECHO (antes del primer header, antes del require y antes del if) y ver si te muestra alguno de ellos. De todas formas, en los log de apache tendras mas info al respecto de tu error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para empezar, cambia la ruta, la tienes aparentemente mal:

```
require_once "../models/alumno.php";
```

debería ser esta, vista la captura de tu estructura de archivos:

```
require_once "./models/alumno.php";
```

porque la carpeta `models` es hija de la carpeta `Alumnos`, donde está el index.php, y no "hermana", por lo tanto no hace falta que apuntes un nivel atrás para encontrarla.

Para aprender mejor como funcionan las rutas relativas o absolutas revisa [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/522761/especificar-un-ruta-de-archivo-txt-en-php/522771#522771).

Luego si salen más errores ya los iremos viendo.

Comment: En efecto este era mi problema..! Muchas gracias..!! :D

Comment: Bien, me alegro que te haya funcionado :-) Saludos