# Cargar recursos desde otra subcarpeta PHP

Tags: php, html, xampp

Tengo un inconveniente, e creado una web en la que en la raiz de esta tengo una carpeta llamada include en la cual tengo la conexion a mi base de datos, un header y un footer, tal cual como se ve en la imagen

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este header y footer lo puedo cargar desde el index que se ve aqui, mi problema empieza cuando en la carpeta clientes creo una vista y le intento cargar el header y el footer, me carga pero sin sus propiedades visuales, revisando encuentro que al hacer el include sobre el header y el footer la ruta de los complementos y estilos se altera y me dice que no los encuentra.

este es mi header
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No se si lo este haciendo de manera correcta, pero quiero tener por cada carpeta sus vistas separadas pero llamar el header y el footer desde la carpeta principal.

Muchas gracias por la ayuda de antemano
Dios les bendiga.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En este caso, tal como tienes estructurado tu sistema de *includes*, es mejor que uses **rutas absolutas** en tu *header* para invocar al resto de archivos. Actualmente estas usando **rutas relativas**, las cuales te funcionarán bien tan solo desde archivos que esten al mismo nivel que las otras carpetas, es decir, la raiz.

Por ejemplo, estas poniendo esto:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="plugins/summernote/summernote-bs4.min.css">
```

lo cual, data tu estructura de archivos, si el archivo de la url esta en la raiz, como el *index.php* que se ve allí, no es problema y lo encuentra bien. Es decir, desde aquí funciona bien:

```
https://tudominio.com/index.php
```

Pero si tu url está en una subcarpeta (directorio) **Clientes/**, por ejemplo:

```
https://tudominio.com/Clientes/index.php
```

entonces el `href` relativo que usas se cree que el archivo está aquí:

```
Clientes/plugins/summernote/summernote-bs4.min.css
```

**La solución pasa por usar rutas absolutas** en los `href` y `src` que necesites poner en tu *header*. **Las rutas absolutas son las que empiezan desde la raíz de tu web**, y ésta se indica con una barra al principio de la ruta `/`, así:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/plugins/summernote/summernote-bs4.min.css">
```

de este modo estarás invocando a esos archivos de forma unívoca desde cualquier carpeta o ruta de tu sitio web.

Para estar seguros de cual es la raíz de tu web, puedes crear un archivo PHP con este contenido:

```
echo $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"];
```

y te mostrará la ruta completa hasta la raíz de tu web, y de ese modo sabrás qué representa la primera barra `/` y dónde está apuntando, y a partir de ahí podrás poner todas las carpetas bien hasta llegar donde deseas.

En esta [otra respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/522761/especificar-un-ruta-de-archivo-txt-en-php/522771#522771) explico un poco lo que son las **rutas relativas y absolutas**.

Comment: Buen dia masterguru, segun entiendo, colocandole el / al iniciar la ruta, ya quedaria absoluta.
Le agrege el / pero no tube ningun resultado, 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/plugins/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4/css/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4.min.css">

Tambien agregue la ruta completa con el C:/ etc y tampoco
<link rel="stylesheet" href="C:/xampp/htdocs/gps/Dashboard/plugins/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css">

Comment: ¿Pero se lo agregastes a todos los relativos? ¿O solo a ese?  Ese era un ejemplo para que lo hicieras en todos los demas.  Por otra parte, si pulsas sobre el boton derecho en cualquier espacio vacio de tu web y seleccionas **Inspeccionar** se te abrirá el inspector, y desde allí, seleccionando la pestaña **Consola** podrás ver si las peticiones a tus archivos js, css, etc, estan bien cargadas o te aparecen marcas en rojo conforme no los encuentra (error 404). Asi podras depurar mejor los que te faltan.

Comment: Por último, no me fijé que tu raiz no parece la que aparece en la captura, sino la que viene a partir de **htdocs**, por lo tanto seguramente deberás usar como ruta, antes de `plugins/`, esto otro: `/gps/Dashboard/`, de tal forma que seria así: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/gps/Dashboard/plugins/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4/css/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4.min.css">`... Tendrias que averiguar cual es tu DocumentRoot para estar seguros del todo.

Comment: La ruta completa a C: no te funcionará si eso lo sirve un servidor web (apache, ngnix, etc).

Comment: Los anteriores eran lineas de pruebas para que vea la manera en la que lo escribi, entinedo que debe ser escrito en todos los recursos, lo que me dices de la consola ya lo habia echo, logro evidenciar que aun el recurso no carga me dice que no lo encuentra

Comment: respecto al segundo comentario, lo probe asi y si funciona mi hermnao muchas gracias, continuare haciendo pruebas cualquier cosa te comento

Muchas gracias Buen dia

Comment: Perfecto, me alegro, para la próxima vez que quieras usar rutas absolutas, primero averigua cual es tu documentRoot haciendo un `echo $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]` y te mostrara la ruta completa hasta la raíz de tu web, y de ese modo sabrás que representa la primera barra `/` y donde está apuntando, y a partir de ahí podrás poner todas las carpetas bien hasta llegar donde deseas.

Comment: Muchas gracias Hermano